# What is this(server hardware)?

Tags: hardware

What is this adapter called?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the name is "riser card".

[Riser card Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riser_card)

> A riser card is a printed circuit board that picks up a multitude of signal lines (often bused) via a single connector (usually an edge connector) on a mainboard and distributes them via dedicated connectors on the card.

[image]

Comment: yes. Riser cards are meant to use full height cards in cases with reduced height. They are often made for their specific case, and cant be used on other boards.

Comment: Gosh, if I didn't know any better, I swear the photo reminds me of my IBM PS/2... I'm pretty sure it is!